Session in Spring Security with LDAP authentication for a SPA (Single Page App)
The project I work on has it's own authentication mechanisms implemented, but because they've been transplanted from another project there is many unnecessary features. This is why I decided to try and replace them with Spring solutions in a hope to reduce codebase size. This has been one hell of a journey and I'm stuck.
The architecture is this: there is React frontend + Spring Boot backend app. Frontend files are put in Java's resources folder and then they are served by Spring's Tomcat. At the same time backend exposes a number of endpoints for frontend to use, including login, logout, configuration and all sorts of data endpoints. Frontend calls the login endpoint with username + passowrd in body  to set session cookie which should then allow it to call other endpoints without providing credentials each time.
I found this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap where they use a combination of authorizeHttpRequests + formLogin. It's a nice start, but a lot of customisations are necessary since my project is an SPA.
I've managed to make the LDAP authentication work, but, unfortunately, I can't force any of the the authenticated enpoints to work. They all return 403 Forbidden status - I dived waaay deeper into Spring's guts than I ever wished in order to find out that session is not carried between the requests. Symptoms are as follows:

session cookie, JSESSIONID, is not set and ApplicationSessionCookieConfig#createSessionCookie is never called,
authentication is an AnonumousAuthenticationToken everywhere - for example AuthorizationFilter#getAuthentication returns aforementioned token and thus access is denied,
security context holder strategy is InheritableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy - I don't know if that's good or not
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#loadDeferredContext calls request.getSession(false) which returns null - the session doesn't exist
at the end, since there is no Authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder, the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter kicks in.

I provide my SecurityConfiguration below. I've left lots of commented code to give you an idea of what I've tried:
package com.visiona.suka.gui.adapter.in.web;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CsrfConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter;

import static com.visiona.suka.gui.adapter.in.web.CspFilter.NONCE_PLACEHOLDER;
import static org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT_PATH = "/v1/login";
    static final String LOGOUT_ENDPOINT_PATH = "/v1/logout";
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    private static final String DEFAULT_CSP_PATTERN =
        "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'nonce-" + NONCE_PLACEHOLDER + "'";
    private static final String CONFIGURATION_PATH = "/v1/configuration";
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Value("${adapter.in.web.cspPattern:" + DEFAULT_CSP_PATTERN + "}")
    public String cspPattern;
    @Value("${adapter.in.web.csrfProtection.enabled:true}")
    private boolean isCsrfProtectionEnabled;
    @Value("${server.ssl.enabled:false}")
    private boolean isHttpsEnabled;

    private static AuthenticationManager createAndSetAuthenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
            http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
        http.setSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class, authenticationManager);
        http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint entryPoint = new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint();
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = createAndSetAuthenticationManager(http);

        configureCsrf(http);

        http.headers((headers) ->
                headers.xssProtection(HeadersConfigurer.XXssConfig::disable) // Most modern browsers don't support it
                    .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::deny) // Block iframes
                    .httpStrictTransportSecurity(httpStrictTrans ->
                        httpStrictTrans.includeSubDomains(true)
                            .maxAgeInSeconds(31_536_000)
                    )
        ).httpBasic(basic -> basic
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<BasicAuthenticationFilter>() {
                    @Override
                    public <O extends BasicAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O authenticationFilter) {
                        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(new JsonBasicAuthenticationConverter());
                        return authenticationFilter;
                    }
                })
//            .securityContextRepository()
//        ).sessionManagement(session -> session
//                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
//                .addSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new CsrfAuthenticationStrategy())
//                    .addSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy())

//        ).securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
//                .requireExplicitSave(true)
            //this is default anyway:
//            .securityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
//                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
//                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
//            ))
        ).authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                //note: ordering of matchers matters - more specific must come first
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST, LOGIN_ENDPOINT_PATH)).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST, LOGOUT_ENDPOINT_PATH)).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, CONFIGURATION_PATH)).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v1/**/*").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
//        );
        ).formLogin(customizer -> customizer
            .loginProcessingUrl("/v1/login")
            .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                response.getOutputStream().println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authentication.getAuthorities()));
            })
            .failureHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            })
            .permitAll()
        ).logout(customizer -> customizer
            .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_ENDPOINT_PATH)
            .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value())
            )
        ).rememberMe(Customizer.withDefaults());

//legit replacement of filters doesn't work, they are overriden at a later stage
//        http.addFilterBefore(new JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
//        .class);
//        http.addFilter(new JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter());

        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);

        DefaultSecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain = http.build();
        JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter =
            new JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager);
        replaceAuthenticationFilter(securityFilterChain, authenticationFilter);
        return securityFilterChain;
    }

    /**
     * UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter doesn't manage to read credentials from the request.
     */
    private static void replaceAuthenticationFilter(DefaultSecurityFilterChain builtChain, JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter replacement) {
        List<Filter> filters = builtChain.getFilters();
        for (int i = 0; i < filters.size(); i++) {
            Filter filter = filters.get(i);
            if (filter instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) {
                filters.set(i, replacement);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is called before securityFilterChain, so the configuration of security chain already has LDAP manager
     * configuration.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        String url = "(censored)";
        String base = "(censored)";
        String user = "(censored)";
        String password = "(censored)";
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(url);
        contextSource.setBase(base);
        contextSource.setUserDn(user);
        contextSource.setPassword(password);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator populator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(
            contextSource,
            "");
        populator.setGroupSearchFilter("(member={0})");
        populator.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
        populator.setSearchSubtree(true);
        populator.setRolePrefix("");

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("distinguishedName={0}")
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(populator)
            .contextSource(contextSource);

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("cn={0}")
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(populator)
            .contextSource(contextSource);

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(populator)
            .contextSource(contextSource);

    }

    private Customizer<CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> getCsrfConfigurerCustomizer() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieCustomizer(responseCookieBuilder -> responseCookieBuilder
            .secure(isHttpsEnabled)
            .sameSite("Lax")
            .httpOnly(false)
        );
        return csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfTokenRepository)
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler());
    }

    private void configureCsrf(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (!isCsrfProtectionEnabled) {
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
            LOG.warn("Protection against CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery also known as XSRF) is disabled");
            return;
        }

        http.csrf(getCsrfConfigurerCustomizer())
            .addFilterAfter(new EagerCsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}


Supporting classes where I extract credentials from JSON body because neither httpBasic (which is commented in the snippet above) nor formLogin can do that out of the box:
package com.visiona.suka.gui.adapter.in.web;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import static com.visiona.suka.gui.adapter.in.web.SecurityConfiguration.LOGIN_ENDPOINT_PATH;

public class JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_ENDPOINT_PATH,
            "POST"));
        this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
            response.getOutputStream().println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authentication.getAuthorities()));
        });
        this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return obtainFieldFromBody(request, this.getUsernameParameter());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return obtainFieldFromBody(request, this.getPasswordParameter());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String obtainFieldFromBody(HttpServletRequest request, String fieldName) throws IOException {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef
            = new TypeReference<>() {};
        HashMap<String, String> parsedBody = objectMapper.readValue(request.getReader(), typeRef);
        return parsedBody.get(fieldName);
    }
}


package com.visiona.suka.gui.adapter.in.web;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationConverter;

public class JsonBasicAuthenticationConverter extends BasicAuthenticationConverter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken convert(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            .unauthenticated(username, password);
        result.setDetails(this.getAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        return result;
    }

    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return obtainFieldFromBody(request, "username");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return obtainFieldFromBody(request, "password");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String obtainFieldFromBody(HttpServletRequest request, String fieldName) throws IOException {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef
            = new TypeReference<>() {};
        HashMap<String, String> parsedBody = objectMapper.readValue(request.getReader(), typeRef);
        return parsedBody.get(fieldName);
    }
}

As you can see - it's a mess. Any pointers are going to be much appreciated. Even though I'm a full-stack developer, I'm mostly focused on frontend and although I've learnt a lot about Spring recently I'm still very far from an expert - perhaps there is some simple misconception I believe? It's also possible this unwanted behaviour is indirectly caused by some other parts of my appliction - I disabled the most probable culprits i.e. CspFilter and CSRF protection, but the problem persist - maybe there is something else I could try? Again, any pointers, please.
